# Change field value with annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have a field annotated like this:

```
@TryMe
private List testList
```

I want to instantiate List from a class that extends AbstractProcessor. I have a method :

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) { 
for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(TryMe.class)) {    } }
```

in that class.  As you can see i can get the annotatedElement, but how do i put the value of an ArrayList in the element testList ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But to set a value you would have to have actual instance of class, and here you have only class.

Comment: use reflection to set the field value?

Comment: but how will i get the instance at this level? @bayou.io